# Other ways to resize image than Graphics.DrawImage

Tags: .net, gdi+, drawing

Don't ask me why but i can't use this method because I need to create 2 image objects to make it work.

I want to be able to resize a single Image object without needing to create another one. Is this possible and how?

Comment: 2topicstarter: Is your question actually about .NET or GDI+ (which is mostly used in native environment)?

Comment: Well isn't GDI+ a part of .NET?

Comment: In short, no. Usually when programming in C#, you would use WPF, which hides from you the details about drawing (maybe the same is with WinForms, I am not sure). In fact, WPF can use DirectX as drawing backend, too.

However when you are developing a native application, usually you use either GDI or GDI+ directly.

Comment: I wan't to use wpf but i don't think it is available for asp.net. I am using it for a website.

Comment: For a WebSite you could use a XBAP application if you want to use WPF. But I don't see any benefit from it.

Comment: Could you explain a little more what do you need the resized image for? Your first post didn't said nothing about a website. If you give some more info I'm sure I can help you.

Comment: Well I guess if GDI+ does not have other methods for resizing besides DrawImage i am in a dead end, there is nothing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The height and width of an `Image` object are fixed at the time the `Image` object is constructed. This limitation exists in the underlying GDI+ API.

If you do not need to modify the `Image`, perhaps it is acceptable to scale it every time it is rendered. For example, in a `Control.Paint` event, you can use `Graphics.DrawImage` to render it directly onto the `PaintEventArgs.Graphics` context. This will allow you to draw the image at different sizes without creating additional `Image` objects.

Comment: I'm with  you that once created an Image object, it cannot be changed, so it will always need another image to copy to the resized image.

Answer (score 2):

If your reason is a problem of Memory or something like that (very large image). You could try to open it and resize it using [Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Matrix` to resize image. you must create a matrix and scale it and set it to your `Graphics` object.

```
Matrix mx = new Matrix();
mx.Scale(2.0f,2.0f);
graphics.Transform=mx;
graphics.DrawImage(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put `Image` into a `ViewBox`.

See http://www.wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html